# Accessing values from an option block HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to read the value that is selected by user in the form, populated via a database. I tired but found only static populated topics.
Also how can I set a default selection when the list is dynamically populated?

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST'>
//Other options to enter

<select name="crit">
$sql= "select Criteria from criterias";
$result= mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['Criteria'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Sub" value="Submit">
</form>


$POST['crit']; //dosen't work
```

Also what is the use of owner1 tags? I took that piece from net and it was populating like I wanted.

Comment: It's not $POST it's $_POST :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if its the first row and set the selected attribute

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST'>
//Other options to enter

<select name="crit">
$sql= "select Criteria from criterias";
$result= mysql_query($sql);
$count = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option " . ($count++ == 0 ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") . " value=\"owner1\">" . $row['Criteria'] . "</option>";
}

// Access with 
$_POST["crit"]
```

Comment: Okay that helps me set a default value. Now how can I know the selected value so as to save it in a db?

Comment: @akp $_POST["crit"], server variables start with $_ such as $_SERVER and $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do since the value in your option is will ALL be **owner1**. but you could add a condition in your while loop to select an option by default.

```
//set any id in your url, this way we can match anything in your db with $GET['id']
if ($row['Criteria'] == $_GET['id']) 
{
    echo "<option value=\"owner1\" selected>" . $row['Criteria'] . "</option>";
}
else
{
     echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['Criteria'] . "</option>";
}
```

but if you want to auto select the 1st option do this.

```
$i = 0;
$selected= '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     if ($i == 0) $selected = 'selected'; 
     echo "<option value=\"owner1\" ".$selected.">" . $row['Criteria'] . "</option>";
    else 
     $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! That was a mistake due to ignorance. I was trying to do what Akam showed. Thank You